# The size of the font, icon, and everything else in GUI of RPi

Tags: raspbian, gui

I'm a noob here, and I'm struggling before even starting to code anything. My RPi's gui shows everything really tiny. Is there any way I can make things bigger, including the font size, icon size, and Arduino IDE, which is on the screen, size? I tried to get into "/boot/config.txt" and change the size but nothing really changed. What should I look for on google? I was looking for "RPi screen resolution" but I couldn't really find a right one for me. Everything is too small that I cannot really work on anything like this.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Go to 'Appearance Settings' (Start menu / Preferences).
In the tab 'Default' you can change settings to large, medium and small screens.
Setting it to 'large screen' should make everything bigger.