# Increase window menu font size

Tags: raspbian

I'm running plain Raspbian 9 Stretch.  Is there a way to increase font size of window menus such as the Chromium address bar or the Idle file menu, circled red?  Terminal file menu adjusts when I change appearance settings, circled green.  Thanks for any help with this
[image: different font sizes]

Comment: try the solution suggested here.. [the-size-of-the-font-icon-and-everything-else-in-gui-of-rpi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/87026/the-size-of-the-font-icon-and-everything-else-in-gui-of-rpi)